# What happened to CMake's --target argument?

Tags: cmake

With CMake version 3.19.2 I can use `--target` argument to build specific targets, instead of `all`.
For example `--target tests` to build tests.
However, with CMake 3.22.1 I'm getting an error like this:

```
CMake Error: Unknown argument --target
CMake Error: Run 'cmake --help' for all supported options.
```

You can see the manual of CMake here:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html 
(There is a drop-down list for version selection)

It describes the `--target` argument, and It doesn't seem any different from what it was earlier. Nonetheless, after switching from 3.19.2 to 3.22.1 it doesn't let me use `--target`.

@EDIT thank you for your feedback, here's what I use:

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCROSS_COMPILER_PREFIX=<some_prefix> -Dsomeothervariables=1 --target tests $directory_with_cmake_project
```

It works with 3.19.2, but executing the same thing with cmake 3.22.1 causes the error.
I expect that the order of providing `-G Ninja`, variables, target directory and `--target` matters, but I haven't managed to get it to work in any order I could think of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CMake is composed of stages - first you configure the project, *then* you build it:

- configuration stage `cmake <sourcedir> ...` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem
- build stage `cmake --build <builddir> ...` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project

`--target` argument if for the build stage, and it is invalid for configuration stage, hence your error.

Comment: Yes, I had omitted the fact that target name could be just passed to ninja after running CMake, as I was using ninja explicitly. This answer helped me make a solution that **works with both versions** of CMake (`ninja tests` **after** running cmake without `--target`). It's still a bit unclear for me how it **did work with cmake 3.19.2** though, but my problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

CMake prints this message, if you haven't specified a directory to build by passing `--build <some dir>` first. (The `--target` option only if mentioned in this usage version of the cmake command line tool, see [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project).)

**Wrong**

```
cmake --target foo
CMake Error: Unknown argument --target
CMake Error: Run 'cmake --help' for all supported options.
```

**Correct**
(assuming in the subdirectory `build` of the current working directory contains a configured cmake project with a target `foo`).

```
cmake --build build --target foo
```